# modifying 2 lists and giving them scores

Tags: python-3.x, list, comparison

I want to make a output file which is simply the input file with the value of each byte incremented by one.

here is the expected output:

04 fb 56 13 21 67 68 51 e9 ac

which also will be in hexadecimal notation. I am trying to do that in python3 using the following command:

Comment: `import numpy as np;(np.array(a)>np.array(b)).sum(),(np.array(a)<np.array(b)).sum()`